# How to redirect a page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I usually do `header("Location: url");` as a basis of redirecting my pages into other page.

Previously, I noticed that the header function was not functioning in my WordPress page.

What is the best way to do it? `wp_redirect($url);` is not working on my WP.

Answer (score 1):

[wp_redirect()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) is the way to redirect to a different page in WordPress (be sure to use exit after calling the redirect function). If it is not working, you might be using it on the wrong location. Can you show a example of your code?